# How take 2 subcategory under category using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I want to take 2 subcategory under category relation using this but it take only 2 subcategory for one category but why?

Comment: share what you tried so far?

Comment: Provide all the things you have done so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.